# Can you expand your insight "to" a person?

Tags: word-usage

For example, in a case where someone already has insight, and they later developed an insight into a certain person, could it be said as,

> He expanded his insight to Joe.

Comment: Are you implying that someone's insight into all things accumulates into a single entity, which is to say that gaining any insight into any matter would enlarge that entity?

Comment: No.  They could *gain insight into* Joe's psyche for example.  But as stated in a comment to your other question, it really needs to be some attribute of Joe's not Joe himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression *expanded his insight* sounds really weird and a quick search in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) shows that such an expression is very rare.

New Oxford American Dictionary suggests that

> **insight**
>
> the capacity to gain an accurate and deep intuitive understanding of a
> person or thing: *this paper is alive with sympathetic insight into
> Shakespeare.*
>
> • an understanding of this kind: *the signals would give
> marine biologists new insights into the behavior of whales.*

and this is how you should express it:

> He **gained a deeper insight** into to Joe.

though it is always better to write it this way:

> He gained insight into **Joe's behavior** (or some other attribute of Joe's, as suggested by JIM)

as the word *insight* is more commonly used to express the idea of gaining an understanding of a particular problem, situation or thing.

> *insight into the real issue*
>
> *insight into why Natalie is now moving in a new direction*
>
> *insight into the market*
>
> *insight into each child's capabilities*
>
> *insight into the brain's functioning*
>
> *insight into both professional and personal characteristics of potential employees*

Comment: Writing today is such, we can find "About 10,100,000" instances of "insight to" on the Web ("About 714,000" in GoogleBooks). At least some are cases of prepositional use as in OP's example: "A fascinating insight to a drivers life..."; "China Beckons: An Insight to the Culture and National Language", "Simplifying your life: divine insights to uncomplicated living".